# Стиль закрытия/открытия блоков

Tags: javascript

Можете объяснить, почему все считают правильным писать вот так:

```js
if (true) {
    // ...
}
```

```js
if (true) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Вместо:

```js
if (true)
{
    // ...
}
```

```js
if (true)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Ведь второй вариант намного удобнее читать.

---

А так же я часто видел, что пишут пустую строку после `if (true) {` (хоть это и не приято, [Источник](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace--padded-blocks)), я так понимаю для читаемости кода:

```js
if (true) {

   // ...
}
```

Что как раз и избавляет от этой необходимости второй вариант.

Comment: Я там не увидел информации, почему лучше так писать, чем иначе) Просто пример с написанием как в первом варианте.

Comment: Потому что такой стиль [нравится](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218860) Дугласу Крокфорду :)

Comment: И кстати не все считают что правильное именно так :)))

Comment: Оба варианта легко читаемы, но вот кто не ставит пробелы, между `(){}=+-` и etс; например `if(cond){a=b+c-d}` или не открывает блок (`{`), если условие одно ... ребята, вам отдельный котёл приготовлен.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, я полностью согласен про ```не открывает блок ({), если условие одно```, я так раньше делал, но потом задумался.. а стоит ли упускать блок, если в дальнейшем туда может что-то добавится? И понял, что нет, не стоит)

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ. Это всё субъектившина

Comment: "почему все считают" -- кто **все** ?

Comment: @RomanGrinyov что плохого в " не открывает блок ({), если условие одно" ? Если вам не нравится - то это проблемы ваши)) Это всё субъективщина

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что нечитаемо из-за отсутствия видимых границ (большинство девелоперов открывает скобки всегда) + если нужно будет добавить дополнительные действия, то нужно добавлять фигурные скобки.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov  "нечитаемо из-за отсутствия видимых границ" --- вы не видите текст сразу под `if`? )))............  "если нужно будет добавить дополнительные действия" --- а если не нужно? то лишние манипуляции со скобками. Вот и контраргумент...... "большинство девелоперов открывает скобки всегда" --- почему решили, что большинство? Есть какая-то статистика?)) ............Нечитаемо - субъективно. Я вот хорошо читаю и не напрягаюсь)) ....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я работал с множеством проектов и только два раза видел, чтобы не ставили: 1) лет 6 назад, но человек всё-таки стал ставить; 2) буквально в этом году — но там олдскульный сишник. Больше не встречал.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov а у меня ровно противоположный опыт :))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что наверняка это не с JS и PHP в основном :)

Comment: @RomanGrinyov нет. был Java, Javascript, C#  и PHP - так что было где развернуться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    У некоторых джавистов даже больше, они в условиях `if` при одной операции вообще ставят её на ту же строку))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читабельно или нет это все субъективно. А важны стандарты или стили написания кода. Почему важно? Поскольку код написанный различным подчерком читается хуже. Код это продукт работы команды разработчиков. Во избежании проблем с подчерками вводятся стили написания кода. Так вот приведенные примеры это различные [стандарты](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) стили написания кода. У каждого есть свои доводы.

```
while (x == y)
{
    something();
    somethingelse();
} // Allman стиль


while (x == y) {
    something();
    somethingelse();
} // K&R стиль
```

Прошу не ругать за `while` поскольку считаю что здесь важно именно расположение скобок. И пример по ссылке был приведен именно для оператора `while`

Comment: Стоит ли везде придерживаться стиля который нравится мне? (В моем случае это Allman)

Comment: Если выбор стиля это решение команды. И вашем случае это только вы. То какие проблемы.Благо на сегодняшний день есть форматтеры которые преспокойно переводят из одного формата в другой

Comment: Я считаю что придерживаться нужно стандартного стиля команды, какой бы он не был.

Comment: Довольно сложно переучить себя на K&R стиль, после написания на Allman все годы кодинга.

Comment: Да не вопрос. Форматтер вам в помощь.

Comment: В форматере можно использовать Allman  стиль? Иногда хочется использовать форматер, но он все делает в K&R.

Comment: Вы программист напишите этот простой код.

Comment: @OliverPatterson нормальные IDE позволяют сделать настройки на необходимый язык и их использовать. Если вы пишите в блокноте - то, конечно, ни о каких форматированиях речи идти не может

Comment: @AzizUmarov спроси у автора минуса

Comment: Автор минуса был бы благодарен пояснениям минуса